# Find Longest Prefix That is Also a Suffix in String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, slice

[Link to codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/string-prefix-and-suffix/train/javascript)

I need to return the length of the longest prefix that is also a suffix of a string in Javascript.

As far as I understand, the prefixes in `"abcd"` are:

`['a', 'ab', 'abc']`

And the suffixes in `"abcd"` are:

`[ 'bcd', 'cd', 'd' ]`

So the length of the longest prefix that is also a suffix in `"abcd"` in this case is 0, because there are no prefixes that are also suffixes in `"abcd"`.

So far I've been able to figure out how to get the suffixes into an array for comparison, but not the prefixes.

```
function returnLongestPrefixAndSuffix(string) {

  let prefixes = [];
  let suffixes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length -1; i++) {
    prefixes.push(string.slice(i));
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
    suffixes.push(string.slice(i));
  }

  return prefixes + " " + suffixes;

}

console.log(returnLongestPrefixAndSuffix("abcd"));
```

I'm not grasping the concept of how to start at the beginning of a string and add a larger element to the array each time by one character, excluding the element that would include the last one.

Please follow my current logic if possible.

**EDIT**: My code now looks like this:

```
function solve(string) {

    let prefixes = [];
    let suffixes = [];
    let includedList = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
      prefixes.push(string.slice(0, i));
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
      suffixes.push(string.slice(-i));
    }

    console.log(prefixes);
    console.log(suffixes);

    for (let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
        let element = prefixes[i];
        if (suffixes.includes(element) === true) {
            includedList.push(element);
        }
    }

    console.log(includedList);
    if (includedList.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        let overlap = prefixes.filter(value => suffixes.includes(value));
        console.log(overlap);
        let longest = includedList.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
        return longest.length;
    }
}

console.log(solve("abcdabc"));
```

And this is passing 10049 test but failing 163 tests on codewars. I still do not know what to do with the `overlap` variable or how to exclude overlaps from the `includedList` array.

Comment: Aren't suffixes from the end? I mean "b" is not really at the end?

Comment: @JonasWilms Sorry, edited.

Comment: Also, according to the challenge, the prefix and suffix should not overlap, which is a crucial aspect of the problem.

Comment: @YannickK - I don't understand what it means by overlap. Wouldn't `abc` be an overlap in the string `"abcdabc"`? Yet it says that `abc` is the largest prefix + suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function solve(string) {

    for (let i = Math.floor(string.length / 2); i > 0; i--) {

        let prefix = string.slice(0, i);
        let suffix = string.slice(-i);

        if (prefix == suffix) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

console.log(solve("abcdabc"));
```

To account for the overlap, initialize your for-loop like this:

`let i = Math.floor(string.length / 2)`

That will initialize the for-loop at the half-way point in your string, so that you can count down and compare whether or not the prefix == the suffix, starting with the longest.

You could return `prefix.length`, but that will be the same thing as `i`.

Also, be sure to `return 0` outside of the for-loop. Because if you try:

```
if (prefix != suffix) {
    return 0;
   }
```

inside of the for-loop, it will stop counting right there.

Answer (score 1):

To get the prefixes, you can use the second argument of `.slice`:

```
  string.slice(0, i)
```

Note that to get the suffixes, you could also take the string from the end:

```
  string.slice(-i)
```

There is no sense in collecting prefixes and suffixes in arrays, just search for the biggest i where the suffix equals the prefix.

Comment: I think that's what I've done with my updated code, but I'm not grasping how to take the overlap into account.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation of the `slice` function, it may take a second argument: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

So following your logic, one way to get prefixes would be to:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= string.length; i++) {
  prefixes.push(string.slice(0, i));
}
```

EDIT:
Your newest code doesn't work because of two reasons:

1. You may end up with `includedList` being empty, but you still try to get first element out of it.
2. You don't take overlaps into consideration. For the input `aaa` the correct result is `a` since prefix `aa` overlaps with the corresponding suffix. In other words the result can't be longer than half the length of the input.

Comment: Thank you - this works, but I'm not grasping why the prefix array includes `"a"` when we're initializing the the for-loop at index 1. Based on your code, shouldn't the prefix array look like `["b", "bc", "bcd"]`? Doesn't `let i = 1` tell the for loop where to start?

Comment: I get why the slice is increasing every time, because we have `i++` in the for-loop and `(0, i)` is what's starting with `a` - I just don't understand why it has to be `let i = 1` instead of `let i = 0`?

Comment: Yes, but `i` is used as the second argument to the `slice` function. So the first argument which is `0` means we start the slice at the position `0` which is letter `a`, and the second argument, which is `i`, says where do we end our slice (but excluding the character on that position).

Comment: Right - that part of it makes sense. I just don't get the `let i = 1;` - don't we want to start iterating at index 0?

Comment: `"abcde".slice(0, 3)` translates to "we want a slice that starts at position 0 and end at position 3, excluding", which is "abc".

Comment: So following this logic `slice(0, 2)` would give you `ab`, `(0, 1)` -> `a`, `(0, 0)` -> an empty string `""`.

Comment: I know but I'm trying to understand the initialization block in the for loop `(let i = 1;` - why is that `(let i = 1;` instead of `(let i = 0;`? Doesn't `let i = 0` or `let i = 1` also determine where the slices will take place?

Comment: If you'd use `let i = 0` you would include an empty string to the array - just try it yourself. Since you're not interested in an empty string it makes sense to start the loop at `i = 1`.

Comment: I see - I never knew that the index value 0 of a string was an empty string?

Comment: You got that wrong - strings are just like array in this case. First character of a string is also at position 0. 
You're confusing what the variable `i` means - it's just a helper variable which is not connected to the position on any of the characters of the string. You only use it in the `slice` function as the argument.

Comment: Okay the issue is because of the nature of the slice() method. It would return an empty string on the first slice because `slice(0,0)` will not return anything from the string. That is why you have to set `i = 1`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know what to do with the `overlap` variable or how to exclude overlaps from the result.